# Why does a range have the function "count"?

Tags: python, range

Unless I'm mistaken, a range can only include unique numbers. So, a number could be in it or not.

I guess only if we want to pass a range as one of many accepted types (dynamic) to some function would it make sense.

However, it seems like if it would go over the whole range to count a number it would be very inefficient.

I tried to time it compared to "`in`", but on my machine it seems they have the same timing. Can that be right?

Answer (score 7):

Because `range()` objects conform to the [`Sequence` ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence), and that ABC has a `.count()` method.

In other words, it is there for completeness sake, so that the object [qualifies as a sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence).

It doesn't have to go across the whole range as it is easy enough to *calculate* if the number is part of the sequence, see [Why is `1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)` so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast)

Comment: Is it possible to see if it is aware that as soon as it finds a match it can stop? It seems to be the case since a similar timing to "in".

Comment: Wow of course, it just has to compare the minimum and maximum...duh... silly question. That answer is very useful: I like range even a lot more.

Comment: For completeness, [Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/rangeobject.c#l366) is what CPython calls when you do `in` on a range object. It appears to be O(1) time. And [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/rangeobject.c#l557) is `.count`, which just calls the contains function if the argument is an integer or boolean. So it too is O(1) most of the time.

Comment: Whether it has to go across the whole range depends on the searched value. For example `range(10**8).count(0.)` takes a few seconds before it returns `1`.

Comment: @superbrain that’s because you passed in a float. See my [answer on how range containment works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast), only integers trigger the fast calculation path.