# How would I reference something akin to an input more than once with list comp in Python?

Tags: python

For example, this simple code for outputting the middle character of a word - if it has a middle character.

```
string = str(input("String: "))

print(list(letter for letter in string if letter == string[((len(string) - 1) // 2)]))
```

Could I have the input inside of the list comp whilst still being able to reference the length of it in another part? Usually I do something like this with my inputs in list comp:

```
print(''.join(str(y) for y in [x for x in str(input("Please enter a string: ")) 
if x.isnumeric() == False]))
```

Just wanting to learn more about list comp's possibilities.

Comment: btw, the `str` in `str(input(...))` is redundant. This is because `input()` always returns a `str`. Just use: `string = input(...)`.

Comment: *Could I have the input inside of the list comp whilst still being able to reference the length of it in another part?* 
No, since Python does not support assignment expressions in list comprehensions.

Comment: @RichardNeumann reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension it seems that it is possible. However, I think the resulting code won't be too readable.

Comment: @EyalGolan Clarification:  Assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable expression.

Comment: @RichardNeumann But isn't this what is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642577/multiline-user-input-with-list-comprehension-in-python-3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to store it inside its own list and unpack it using `for`

`string = input("String: ")`

would become

`for string in [input("String: ")]`

```
>>> print([letter for string in [input("String: ")] for letter in string if letter == string[(len(string) - 1) // 2]])
String: abcde
['c']
```

formatted over multiple lines:

```
>>> print(
...     [letter for string in [input("String: ")]
...             for letter in string
...             if letter == string[(len(string) - 1) // 2]]
... )
```

Also, your logic may have undesired behaviour.

```
String: abcdecccccc
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Aha, completely missed that lmao. Converted another thing a function I had that did this into list comp and just didn't clock the loop ig. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to cram something like this onto one line I'd use a `lambda`:

```
>>> print((lambda x: x[(len(x) - 1) // 2])(input()))
middle
d
```

In this case I think readability is vastly improved by doing the variable assignment on its own line, though.