# make a program choose number 1 until 100

Tags: python-2.7, loops, if-statement

How to make the program choose a value from 1 to 100? The program cannot print the correct value

```
while True:
    regage = raw_input('Enter your age:')
    if regage not in range(1,100):
        print 'Please put an apropriate number for your age'
    else:
        print 'you are', regage,'years old'
```

Comment: you mean you want to break out of the while True if the age is within 1 to 100? Then just put a "break" statement within that final else statement. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break

Comment: No. i mean i can pick a value from 1 to 100 not more or less and can print the value that i pick

Comment: Tough luck on your 101-year-old users, huh?

Comment: Nope. I'm still 101 years too early to be a coder

Comment: You can use  `1 <= regage <= 100` instead of `range(1,100)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. The problem was that `raw_input` returns a string, so the value should be converted to an integer before you can check if it's in the array of integers that `range` returns.

```
while True:
    regage = raw_input('Enter your age:')
    if int(regage) not in range(1,101):
        print 'Please put an apropriate number for your age'
    else:
        print 'you are', regage,'years old'
```

Also, I changed the range to include 100.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. `range(1,100)` generates integers from 1 to 99, excluding 100. Test your code with 100 and you will see. Also, note that `range` generates a list of integers. If the range was larger (like checking 1 to 1,000,000) this would be noticeably inefficient. There is no reason to use `range` -- just use an `if x>1 and x<101` style test.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Interestingly, if this were Python3 this would be just as efficient as the alternative you suggest: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3). But on Python2 (which the tag says it is) you are absolutely correct.