# Why is range(0) == range(2, 2, 2) True in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, identity, python-internals

Why do ranges which are initialized with different values compare equal to one another in Python 3?

When I execute the following commands in my interpreter:

```
>>> r1 = range(0)
>>> r2 = range(2, 2, 2)
>>> r1 == r2
True
```

The result is `True`. Why is this so? Why are two different `range` objects with different parameter values treated as equal?

Comment: A short but IMHO sufficient answer would also be "because both ranges are equal". Note the difference between `is` and `==`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

#### The `range` objects are special:

Python will compare **[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)** objects as *[Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)*. What that essentially means is that *the comparison doesn't evaluate **how** they represent a given sequence but rather **what** they represent.*

The fact that the `start`, `stop` and `step` parameters are completely different plays no difference here because *they all represent an empty list when expanded*:

For example, the first `range` object:

```
list(range(0))  # []
```

and the second `range` object:

```
list(range(2, 2, 2)) # []
```

*Both represent an empty list* and since two empty lists compare equal (`True`) so will the `range` objects that *represent* them.

As a result, you can have completely different *looking* `range` objects; if they represent the same sequence they will *compare* equal:

```
range(1, 5, 100) == range(1, 30, 100)
```

Both represent a list with a single element `[1]` so these two will also compare equal.

---

#### No, `range` objects are *really* special:

Do note, though, that even though the comparison doesn't evaluate *how* they represent a sequence the result of comparing *can be achieved* using **solely** the values of `start`, `step` along with the `len` of the `range` objects; this has very interesting implications with the speed of comparisons:

```
r0 = range(1, 1000000)    
r1 = range(1, 1000000)

l0 = list(r0)    
l1 = list(r1)
```

Ranges compares super fast:

```
%timeit r0 == r1
The slowest run took 28.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 160 ns per loop
```

on the other hand, the lists..

```
%timeit l0 == l1
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop
```

Yeah..

---

As **[@SuperBiasedMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4374739/superbiasedman)** noted, this only applies to the range objects in Python 3. Python 2 `range()` is a plain ol' function that returns a list while the `2.x` [`xrange`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/rangeobject.c#l185) object doesn't have the comparing capabilies (*[and not only these..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3?rq=1)*) that `range` objects have in Python 3.

Look at **[@ajcr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014301/4952130)** for quotes directly from the source code on Python 3 `range` objects. It's documented in there what the comparison between two different ranges actually entails: Simple quick operations. The [`range_equals`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f37d372927a4c2c843e2813c32354979c682919/Objects/rangeobject.c#L437) function is utilized in the *[`range_richcompare` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f37d372927a4c2c843e2813c32354979c682919/Objects/rangeobject.c#L468)* for `EQ` and `NE` cases and assigned to the *[`tp_richcompare` slot for `PyRange_Type` types](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f37d372927a4c2c843e2813c32354979c682919/Objects/rangeobject.c#L723)*.

I believe the implementation of `range_equals` is pretty readable (because it is nice as simple) to add here:

```c
/* r0 and r1 are pointers to rangeobjects */

/* Check if pointers point to same object, example:    
       >>> r1 = r2 = range(0, 10)
       >>> r1 == r2
   obviously returns True. */
if (r0 == r1)
    return 1;

/* Compare the length of the ranges, if they are equal 
   the checks continue. If they are not, False is returned. */
cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r0->length, r1->length, Py_EQ);
/* Return False or error to the caller
       >>> range(0, 10) == range(0, 10, 2)  
   fails here */
if (cmp_result != 1)
    return cmp_result;

/* See if the range has a lenght (non-empty). If the length is 0
   then due to to previous check, the length of the other range is 
   equal to 0. They are equal. */
cmp_result = PyObject_Not(r0->length);
/* Return True or error to the caller. 
       >>> range(0) == range(2, 2, 2)  # True
   (True) gets caught here. Lengths are both zero. */
if (cmp_result != 0)
    return cmp_result;

/* Compare the start values for the ranges, if they don't match
   then we're not dealing with equal ranges. */
cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r0->start, r1->start, Py_EQ);
/* Return False or error to the caller. 
   lens are equal, this checks their starting values
       >>> range(0, 10) == range(10, 20)  # False
   Lengths are equal and non-zero, steps don't match.*/
if (cmp_result != 1)
    return cmp_result;

/* Check if the length is equal to 1. 
   If start is the same and length is 1, they represent the same sequence:
       >>> range(0, 10, 10) == range(0, 20, 20)  # True */
one = PyLong_FromLong(1);
if (!one)
    return -1;
cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r0->length, one, Py_EQ);
Py_DECREF(one);
/* Return True or error to the caller. */
if (cmp_result != 0)
    return cmp_result;

/* Finally, just compare their steps */
return PyObject_RichCompareBool(r0->step, r1->step, Py_EQ);
```

I've also scattered some of my own comments here; look at *[@ajcr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014301/4952130)* for the Python equivalent.

Comment: Would it also compare equal to a `list` with the same contents? Is this guaranteed somewhere, or just an interesting side effect of an implementation?

Comment: @MarkRansom It doesn't, equality across sequence types results in inequality. I believe it is mentioned in the reference manual on comparisons, I'll try and find the relevant part and add it to the answer.

Comment: You might want to note that this all only applies to Python 3. In 2, `range` returns a normal list, and `xrange` returns an `xrange` type object, which doesn't do the intelligent comparison. `xrange(0) == xrange(2, 2, 2)` returns `False`.

Answer (score 17):

Direct quote from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) (emphasis mine):

> Testing range objects for equality with == and != compares them as
>   sequences. That is, **two range objects are considered equal if they
>   represent the same sequence of values**. (Note that two range objects
>   that compare equal might have different start, stop and step
>   attributes, for example range(0) == range(2, 1, 3) or range(0, 3, 2)
>   == range(0, 4, 2).)

If you compare `range`s with the "same" list, you'll get inequality, as stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) as well:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never
>   compare equal.

Example:

```
>>> type(range(1))
<class 'range'>
>>> type([0])
<class 'list'>
>>> [0] == range(1)
False
>>> [0] == list(range(1))
True
```

Note that this explicitly only applies to Python 3. In Python 2, where `range` just returns a list, `range(1) == [0]` evaluates as `True`.

Answer (score 13):

To add a few additional details to the excellent answers on this page, two `range` objects `r0` and `r1` are compared [roughly as follows](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/rangeobject.c#l614):

```
if r0 is r1:                 # True if r0 and r1 are same object in memory
    return True
if len(r0) != len(r1):       # False if different number of elements in sequences
    return False
if not len(r0):              # True if r0 has no elements
    return True
if r0.start != r1.start:     # False if r0 and r1 have different start values
    return False
if len(r0) == 1:             # True if r0 has just one element
    return True
return r0.step == r1.step    # if we made it this far, compare step of r0 and r1
```

The length of a `range` object is easily to calculate using the `start`, `stop` and `step` parameters. In the case where `start == stop`, for example, Python can immediately know that the length is 0. In non-trivial cases, Python can just do a [simple arithmetic calculation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/rangeobject.c#l1072) using the `start`, `stop` and `step` values.

So in the case of `range(0) == range(2, 2, 2)`, Python does the following:

1. sees that `range(0)` and `range(2, 2, 2)` are different objects in memory.
2. computes the length of both objects; both lengths are 0 (because `start == stop` in both objects) so another test is needed.
3. sees that `len(range(0))` is 0. This means that `len(range(2, 2, 2))` is also 0 (the previous test for inequality failed) and so the comparison should return `True`.

Comment: I *just* edited my answer to add exactly this, was going to also add the quote from the source but I can now link it my answer to yours.

Comment: Thanks for linking, @Jim. Your answer (and the others) addresses the question perfectly - mine was really just a footnote intended for people who might be curious about the CPython implementation.

Comment: Yup, I'm one of those interested, literally had the hg.python tab open when I noticed a new answer. No need to add it now, you got that covered :-)

Comment: In 2. Do you mean "both _lengths_ are the same, so another test is needed"?

Comment: @gnasher729: yep, that's it. Thanks, I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

`res = range(0) == range(2, 2, 2)`

Where:

```
range(0)
```

means the range from `0` to `0` - `0` steps (here `step` equals to default value `1`), list without values.

```
range(2, 2, 2)
```

means the range from `2` to `2` with step equals to `2`, list without values.

So, these ranges are really equal

Answer (score 7):

`range(0)` returns `range(0,0)`. You start from 0 up to 0 with step 1, which is undefined since the third argument can't be 0 [by default]. You can't reach 0 with 1. No counter's action in place, therefore 0.

`range(2, 2, 2)` returns `range(2, 2, 2)`. You start from 2 up to 2 but with step of 2. Which again, is basically 0 since you don't count up to anything.

```
range(0) == range(2,2,2)
```

**True** and **exactly** the same.

Comment: `range(2,2,2)` is in no way "basically 0"