# Type of range, map and zip

Tags: python

Why are some in-built functions, like `range`, `map` and `zip`, of type `type`, while other functions, like, `eval`, `repr` and `sum`, of type `builtin_function_or_method`?

I understand that `int`, `float`, `list`, etc. are type `type` because they are implemented as classes. But `range`, `map` and the sort are functions which return iterables. Are these also implemented as classes? If so, why?

**Edit:** I just noticed that `type(range(0,1))` is `range` and `type(map(func,arr))` is type `map`. So they are indeed implemented as classes.

What advantage does this implementation have over implementing them as `list`?

Comment: The `range` and `map` functions return objects of those types. `range` in particular isn't just an ordinary iterable.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Why is this so?

Comment: Custom types may be lazy while being 100% conformant with "iterable" interface. Since they are very often used in iterating context, there is an immediate decrease in memory usage when laziness is applied. It's basic reason for switching to lazy sequences in common built-in functions in Python 3.

Comment: @Rogalski I'm really sorry, but when do you call something **lazy**??

Comment: Lazy means they compile but don't calculate until actually called during runtime

Comment: @MayurH Like when you use `yield`?

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 yes, exactly - lazy evaluation basically means *"not calculated until (and unless) actually needed"*

Comment: Yes, in Python one of essential lazy types is `generator`. Another lazy type is `range`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3

Comment: @Rogalski Thank you. So, `map` and `zip` essentially work the same way too? Or are they unrelated?