# How to update value in main loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have `while` loop in `for` loop. And, i want to update value `l` from `while` loop to `for` loop.
Because, on this case is, for example: `l==5` is in while loop, `l==1` is in `for` loop.

```
  for l in range(len(csvLines)):
     if ";" in str(csvLines[l][:2]):
         objectType = int(csvLines[l][:1])
         while objectType == 0:
             l = l+1
             if ";" in str(csvLines[l][:2]):
                 objectType = int(csvLines[l][:1])
             else:
                 objectType = int(csvLines[l][:2])
         else:
             pass
     else:
         objectType = int(csvLines[l][:2])
```

Comment: Make a different variable you're `l` are getting redefined but I don't quite get what you're trying to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change `l` for the current `for` iteration, but as soon as the next `for` iteration begins, `l` is assigned the next value of `range`. If you want to modify iteration index, use `while` for example like this.

```
l = 0  # you have to initialize it manually
while l < len(csvLines):
   ...
   l += 1   # you have to increase it manually at the end of the current iteration
```

Note: when increasing `l` in the loop, you have to make sure that it's still `< len(csvLines)` or next access to `csvLines[l]` will fail.

Comment: *but I'd avoid that in Python 2* - I'd avoid it *completely* never mind the Python version... :)

Comment: `range` check is very fast in python 3. Check Martijn Pieters best post on the subject, let me find it here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3?s=2|0.5508

Comment: A simple integer comparison check is 1) more obvious as to the intent and 2) faster than the membership test on the range object... By the looks of it - the OP doesn't even need the counter variable, but we'll ignore that for the moment...

Comment: okay, no need for that. But the counter variable is needed everywhere for `csvLines[l]`

Comment: You really should not use `l in range(N)` for such tests, because if `l` is ever *not* an integer you suddenly turned a simple O(1) check into a slow O(N) check. Stick to chained comparisons (or a simple `<` test if you know `l` can't go below 0), which are guaranteed to be O(1) and give you a nice `TypeError` in Python 3 when you created a bug and now have the wrong type.

Comment: that is some subtle trap. Duly noted (answer already edited, but I thought that `while l in range` looked good)