# Python In Operator - Short Circuit

Tags: python, python-internals, short-circuiting

I was reading an interesting post on [Short-Circuiting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting) and wondered if this was true for the `in` operator. My simple testing would conclude that it does not:

```
%%timeit -n 1000
0 in list(range(10))
1000 loops, best of 3: 639 ns per loop

%%timeit -n 1000
0 in list(range(1000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 23.7 µs per loop
# larger the list, the longer it takes. however, i do notice that a higher 
# value does take longer.

%%timeit -n 1000
999 in list(range(1000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 45.1 µs per loop
```

Is there a detailed explanation of why `999` takes longer than `0`. Is the `in` operator like a loop?

Also, is there a way to tell the `in` operator to "stop the loop" once the value is found (or is this the already defaulted behavior that I'm not seeing)?

Lastly- Is there another operator/function that I am skipping over that does what I'm talking about in regards to "short-circuiting" `in`?

Comment: `Is the in operator like a loop?` Yes, when you call `in` with a list, a C loop is invoked, I believe.

Comment: Also, `in` is a conditional operator, not a logical operator, so "short circuiting" does not apply here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, ah! okay. I can't find that in the docs when I Google it. do you have any citations on this?

Comment: `in list` will iterate through the list until it finds the element. If that's what you mean, it is short-circuited: it doesn't carry on looking through the list once the element has been found.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081318/289011) might be interesting too (it is slightly different, to what you're asking since you're converting to `list`, but it is a very interesting explanation on how `range` works)

Comment: @khelwood, Thank you!

Comment: @BorrajaX No, because OP calls `list` on it.

Comment: I made an edit before your comment @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Also, it is still interesting when it comes to range? Besides, isn't this what comments are for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `in` for `list` objects is found in [`list_contains`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5b0e9db1b9698e6ffc43ae41cf3a22ca5a6ba6/Objects/listobject.c#L398). It performs a scan of the list and does exit early if the last comparison has found the element, there's no point in continuing there.

The loop involved is:

```
for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
    cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                       Py_EQ);
```

If `cmp` is `1` (the value returned from [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) for a match), the `for` loop condition (`cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a)`) becomes false and terminates.

For list objects, which are built-in, what is called for `in` is a `C` function (for CPython). For other implementations of Python, this can be a different language using different language constructs.

For user-defined classes in Python, what is called is defined in the [Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) of the Reference Manual, take a look there for a run-down of what gets called.

---

You could also come to this conclusion by timing:

```
l = [*range(1000)]    
%timeit 1 in l
85.8 ns ± 11.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
%timeit 999 in l
22 µs ± 221 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The furthest the element the more you need to scan. If it didn't short-circuit, all `in` operations would result in similar timings.

Comment: I believe I created a Red Herring when i wrapped `list()` around `range()`. with `l` already defined, this clears it up! Does `in` call different "functions" for different data types based on the latter half of the `in` operator? (please excuse my bad nomenclature if I've used the wrong terms)

Comment: @MattR yes, it does. You can take a look at [Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) in the Reference Manual for the full run-down of what is called (which is too much for a comment to include).

Comment: I really appreciate the links to the documentation. I'll read up some more.

Comment: You're welcome @MattR. Thankfully Python's docs are quite good and readable. It's worth reading through them.

Comment: It will also be educating to time the operations for the "range" object alone, without converting it to a list.

Answer (score 4):

Short circuiting does occur. The `in` operator calls the `__contains__` method, which in turn is implemented differently per class (in your case `list`). Searching for `999` takes around double the time as searching for `0`, since half of the work is creating the list, and the other half is iterating through it, which is short circuited in the case of `0`.

Comment: ah! so the double in time would be due to `list(range(x))` being set up?

Comment: Yes. This is the case.

Comment: `which in turn is implemented differently per class` - could you elaborate on this? I feel like there is something important packed inside this statement!

Comment: When creating a new class, Python supports operator overloading. Statements such as `a = A() + 5` can work by implementing `A.__add__(self, other)`. Similarly, when Python runs into `x in y`, it checks if `y`s class implemented the `__contains__ method` and if so, calls `y.__contains__(x)`. If, on the other hand, the method wasn't implemented, a `TypeError` exception will be thrown.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, your comment is correct, my explanation was a simplified version. If `__contains__` isn't impleneted, then it'll try iterating through the object, looking for the requested value. This means it's enough to implement `__iter__`, or even just `__getitem__`. See here for details: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another look with a hashed object, `set`:

```
from time import time

qlist = list(range(1000))
qset = set(qlist)

start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    0 in qlist
print time() - start

start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    999 in qlist
print time() - start

start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    0 in qset
print time() - start

start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    999 in qset
print time() - start
```

Output:

```
0.000172853469849    0 in list
0.0399038791656    999 in list
0.000147104263306i   0 in set
0.000195980072021  999 in set
```

As others have said, the `list` implementation must do a sequential search.  Set inclusion uses a hashed value, and is on par with finding the item in the first element checked.

Comment: `in` is faster in a set than a list, but what does it show regarding short-circuiting?

Comment: I appreciate the optimization piece.

Comment: @Loquacious: this merely highlights the effect of early loop exit with a list; set **in** doesn't short-circuit at all, because the reference is direct.