# What is the time complexity of evaluating if x in range(n) **Python3**

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

It seems that in python 3 the check time to evaluate:

`if x in range(n)`

should be O(1), is it? Can you point me to some documentation?

(In 2.7 ranges are lists so there the time complexity is surely linear)

Comment: I don't know the exact details in how python implement that, but I think this would be linear search, therefore `O(n)`

Comment: @ThuYeinTun See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3, and no it isn't

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, I just saw the duplicate tag. Reading now.