# Counting the items in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

```
p1 = (0, 10, 1)
p2 = (0, -20, -2)
p3 = (0,10,2)
```

Hi,

I have the above code and I'd simply like a quick way to count how many items are in each range without iterating through it? (its part of a few nested loops). So p1 would return 9.

Also is there a better way to pass those variables in to the range function?

right now i'm suing:

```
range(p1[0], p1[1], p1[2])
```

Comment: Shouldn't `p1` return 10, not 9? As this range contains the numbers from 0 to 9 inclusive, in other words, all the digits, which are 10?

Comment: Not a dupe, but see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/4799172

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> p1 = (0, 10, 1)
>>> len(range(*p1))
10
```

`range` objects are clever and don't require iteration to calculate the length.

Comment: *(in python 3)*

Comment: @RafaelC  There is no such thing as a range object in python 2.

Comment: True. Maybe one could interpret *objects returned from `range()`*

Comment: `len(range(sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize**2))` raises an `OverflowError` on my system, interestingly the `len()` call does it (it is a valid `range()` object); this is mentioned briefly in the docs

Comment: can I pass p1, p2, p3 in all at once, or do you have to do that for each variable?

Answer (score 2):

The virtue of this is that you don't have to create a new object to calculate.

```
def c(p):
  return max((p[1] - p[0]) // p[2], 0)

c(p1)

10
```

Comment: it works only for valid parameters. For instance, with (0,10,-1) it would return `-10` while `len(range(0,10,-1))` would return `0`. I would change it to `return max(0, p[1] - p[0]) // p[2])`

Comment: This has the advantage that it works for `p = sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize**2, 1`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simple math? Just calculate difference between start and stop and devoid it on step size. And, finely subtract one from the result

```
((p[1]-p[0])/p[2]) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example to use the [unpacking operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) *. If you have `p1 = (0,10,1)` then you have to unpack the tuple p1 in order to pass its elements as arguments of `range` function. Then you can just use the `len` function to get the length of the range, as follows:

```
print(len(range(*p1)))  # 10
```