# runtime of checking something in range

Tags: python

I want to check if m in between l and h.
I can write

```
if m<=h and m>=l
```

or

```
m in range(l,h+1)
```

The latter one looks better, but does it take more than O(1) time?

Comment: That should be `m in range(l,h+1)`.

Comment: `x in range()` is much slower than checking against two integers.

Comment: What python version?  In python 2, you're creating a list of those elements.  If l and m are far apart, that's a lot of memory to use and throw away.  In python 3 the range class does this under the hood in very fast time without creating the full list.

Comment: Relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3?rq=1

Comment: `x in range(y, z)` is constant time in Python 3. In Python 2, it is linear time

Comment: @snakecharmerb if the `range` object is created ahead of time, it is very comparable (again, assuming Python 3)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I kind of knew range() is like a generator but that __contains__() method under the hood finally solves my doubts.

Answer (score 6):

*O(1)*:

```
if m<=h and m>=l:
    ...
```

*O(n)* in Python 2, but [*O(1)* in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081470/674039):

```
if m in range(l, m+1):
    ...
```

Better style:

```
if low <= m <= high:
    ...
```

Note: The behaviour is **different** if m can be a non-integer (consider a float, for example).

Comment: Thanks but why does the last one work? How is it evaluated?

Comment: @FelixYan The evaluation is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Comment: It's worth noting that `m in range(l, m+1)` and `low <= m <= high` are not equivalent if `m` is a non-integer value (eg. `m = 1.5`). For example, if `low = 0` and `high = 3` then the range test will return false and the comparison operator test will return true.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the first one but you can rewrite it like it:

```
if 1<=m<=h
```

The function `range` create a list and `in` searches if m is in that list. It's worse in performance that two comparisons.

That only applies to python 2, in python 3 both ways are optimal.

Comment: Not in python 3.  In python 3 the range class does not create a list in memory.  Nor does it search it in linear time.