# Python nested for loop faster than single for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, runtime, nested-loops

Why is the nested for loop faster than the single for loop?

```
start = time()

k = 0
m = 0

for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        for l in range(100):
            m+=1

#for i in range(100000000):
#    k +=1

print int(time() - start)
```

For the single for loop I get a time of 14 seconds and for the nested for loop of 10 seconds

Comment: are you using `Python2`? probably yes.

Comment: For context, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3/30081318#30081318).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant context is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3) topic.

In short, `range(100000000)` builds a *huge* list in Python 2, whereas with the nested loops you only build lists with a total of 1000 + 1000 + 100 = 2100 elements. In Python 3, `range` is smarter and lazy like `xrange` in Python 2.

Here are some timings for the following code. Absolute runtime depends on the system, but comparing the values with each other is valuable.

```
import timeit

runs = 100

code = '''k = 0
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        for l in range(100):
            k += 1'''

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=code, number=runs))

code = '''k = 0
for i in range(100000000):
    k += 1'''

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=code, number=runs))
```

Outputs:

**CPython 2.7 - `range`**

```
264.650791883
372.886064053
```

Interpretation: building huge lists takes time.

**CPython 2.7 - `range` exchanged with `xrange`**

```
231.975350142
221.832423925
```

Interpretation: almost equal, as expected. (Nested `for` loops should have slightly
larger overhead than a single `for` loop.)

**CPython 3.6 - `range`**

```
365.20924194483086
437.26447860104963
```

Interpretation: Interesting! I did not expect this. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `Python2`. Range generates a list of numbers, and has to allocate that list. In the first nested loop you are allocating `1000 + 1000 + 100`, so the list size is `2100`, while in the other one the list has a size of `100000000`, which is much bigger.

In `python2` is better to use a `generator`, `xrange()`, a generator yields the numbers instead of building and allocating a list with them.

Aditionally and for further information you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3/30081318#30081318) that it is related to this but in `python3`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `range` creates a list with all of the numbers within the list. Try swapping `range` with `xrange` and you should see them take comparable time or the single loop approach may work a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

during the nested loops python has to allocate `1000+1000+100=2100` values for the counters whereas in the single loop it has to allocate `10M`. This is what's taking the extra time

i have tested this in python 3.6 and the behaviour is similar, i would say it's very likely this is a memory allocation issue.