# Is the iteration protocol used when indexing a range object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, python-internals

Since the range object produces values on demand, does it mean that anytime a range is indexed, the iteration protocol is invoked up to that index?

What I mean is when:

```
>>> R = range(1,11)
>>> print(R[5])
6
```

Since `R[5]` isn't stored in memory, is it calculated every time by creating a new iterator? If not, how is it possible to index a range object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No iterator is created here, and no iteration occurs. The `range` object is implemented such that Python computes the value of `R[5]` on-demand in constant time.<sup>1</sup>

If the index `i` is not negative, the computation boils down to:

```
i * step + start
```

So in the case of your code `R[5]`, this would be `5*1 + 1` which is 6.

If the index `i` is negative, the length of `R` is added to `i` first, and then the value is computed as before:

```
(i + len(R)) * step + start
```

---

#### Python-internals

When you write `R[5]`, this Python syntax is eventually translated into a call to [`PyObject_GetItem`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/abstract.c#L142-L185), which inspects the object `R` to see how it should proceed to find the item at index 5.

`PyObject_GetItem` first checks the [`tp_as_mapping` slot](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L679) of the `range` type. This is not null; it holds a reference to a struct called `range_as_mapping`. `PyObject_GetItem` then checks to see what is in the [`mp_subscript` field](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L622-L626) of this struct:

```C
static PyMappingMethods range_as_mapping = {
        (lenfunc)range_length,       /* mp_length */
        (binaryfunc)range_subscript, /* mp_subscript */
        (objobjargproc)0,            /* mp_ass_subscript */
};
```

As you can see in the snippet above, it finds the [`range_subscript`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L600-L619) function occupying the `mp_subscript` field.<sup>2</sup>

Now `range_subscript` inspects the arguments it was passed (`R` and `5`) to decide if a single index or a slice was requested. The integer `5` means that just a single index is needed and so the function delegates the computation of the value to [`compute_range_item`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L233-L283). This function performs the computation to return the integer 6 as outlined in the first part of this answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> I have assumed you are using CPython: other Python implementations may implement the `range` object differently.

<sup>2</sup> If you were to call `len(R)`, you can see the internal function in `mp_length` that is called to compute the length of `R` (cf. [Why is "1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)" so fast in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/3923281)).

Comment: In addition to these C-level functions, it might be worth mentioning the Python-level `__getitem__` and `__len__`, as well as the sequence protocol.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. It is not.

However `range` supports both iteration protocol and indexing (through **getitem**)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I had a look at the docs for getitem but I am not sure I understand it. If it equates to using self[key] for an object, isn't there still the problem of knowing the value in a virtual sequence (since it's not stored in memory)?