# Evaluate multiple values to a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a bunch of variables that I need to verify whether they are within a determined range.

Below is a quick example to demonstrate what I want to achieve.

```
a=1
b=3
c=5

if 0 <= {a,b,c} <= 6:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I expect it to print yes but it prints no. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

`{a,b,c}` is a set of three values. It's not a value between 0 and 6.

The condition `0 <= {a,b,c} <= 6` actually produces an exception in Python 3, because it doesn't make sense to ask if a set is more or less than a number. If your code prints `"no"`, then you're probably using Python 2.

If you want to check if a condition holds for every value in some sequence, you can use the built-in function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
if all(0 <= x <= 6 for x in (a,b,c)):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I was using Python 2 as you said. Your solution works with both Python 2 and 3. In the future, if I had float numbers would I just cast the variables to int or is there a better solution?

Comment: @Malyk , if you're using Python 2 why you tagged question with `python-3.x`?

Comment: @Malyk This would work the same with floats. There's no problem using `<=` to compare ints and floats.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.x, for integers you can use `all` with `range`:

```
if all(x in range(7) for x in (a, b, c)):
    # your logic
```

For non-integers or Python 2.x, you can use chained operations:

```
if all(0 <= x <= 6 for x in (a, b, c)):
    # your logic
```

The problem with your logic is Python does not implement vectorised operations with comparison operators.

Comment: While this works in this specific example, don't do that. `3.14 in range(7)` will be `False` while `0 <= 3.14 <= 6` continues working as expected.

Comment: @FynnBecker, That's why I stated explicitly `range` works only for integers.

Comment: @jpp I though about this solution but my range is large between 0 and 100,000 and my doing this for many columns. Isn't this time expensive?

Comment: @Malyk, No, `range` objects are very efficient, they don't create an in-memory object. Related: [Why is “1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)” so fast in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/9209546)

Comment: I think the OP is actually using Python 2, so using `range` for this kind of thing isn't necessarily a good idea. In Python 3, the OP's code would have raised an exception.

Comment: @jpp What I'm trying to say is that this is an anti-pattern IMO. Even for integers you shouldn't use `range()`.

Comment: @khelwood, The questions is tagged 3.x

Comment: @FynnBecker, Can you explain / suggest *why* it shouldn't be used for integers?

Comment: @jpp But the OP's code would not produce the output they describe in Python 3, only in Python 2.

Comment: Sorry guys I was using Python 2. It's my mistake I should remove the tag.