# Why this for loop prints twice?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this program:

```
print()
print ('------MENU------')
print ('1. Welcome to Python')
print ('2. Python is fun')
print ('3. This could be a challenge')
print ('4. Exit')
print()
choice = int(input('please enter a choice between 1 to 4: '))
for choice in (1,5):
      if choice ==1:
            print ('Welcome to python')
      elif choice == 2:
            print ('Python is fun')
      elif choice == 3:
            print ('This could be a challenge')
      else:
            break
```

It should print the MENU first and then asks to input an integer. My question is why it prints twice each time I input an integer between 1 to 3?

Comment: Did you mean `if choice in range(1, 5)`?

Comment: `why it prints twice`. Why **what** prints twice?

Comment: @tobias_k I've seen many questions where someone used `while` when they meant `if`. I think this is the first case of `for` that I've seen.

Comment: Why are you looping at all?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of control flow. and variable declaration in python

Comment: The question clearly is: When the user inputs an option between 1 to 3, like 2, the program prints:'Python is fun', 2 times instead of once?!

Answer (score 5):

With `for choice in (1,5):` you tell your program: "Do the following once for `choice = 1` and once for `choice = 5`. Here, the `for` is a for-*loop*, it does not mean "for the case that...".

What you probably meant was `if choice in range(1, 5)`. The `range` is also important, otherwise you will just test whether `choice` is in the tuple `(1, 5)`, i.e. either `1` or `5`. Alternatively, you can also do `if 1 <= choice < 5`.

(Note: After changing the `for` to `if`, you will probably get a problem with the `break`, as that's just allowed in loops. Alternatively, you could use `return` if that code is in a function, or just `exit()` to exit the program, or nothing at all, if it's the last statement in the program anyway.)

Comment: I must say I dislike seeing `range()` in the context of range checks. Even more so when it's suggested to beginners. The latter suggestion of using `if 1 <= choice < 5` is a very clear pattern that continues to work for `float`s. Getting used to using `range()` for range checks can easily lead to confusion.

Comment: @FynnBecker I agree, that's why I added the comparison chaining alternative, but the `in range(...)` is probably what OP had in mind when writing the code. Also, at least in Python 3, and, of course, for `int`, testing `in range(...)` is actually [not that bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/1639625).

Comment: @FynnBecker, Can you explain *why* in Python3 `if in range(1, 6)` is *worse* than `if 1 <= choice < 5`? `3.0 in range(1, 6)` still works, of course, and you have a free, implicit check you aren't allowing a fractional input.

Comment: @jpp I'm aware that as with almost everything there are viable use-cases for it, I don't see any for this concrete problem though. I addressed this because the OP is obviously new to python and recommending `range()` to beginners left a sour taste because of a certain popular book. As for using `range()` to implicitly ensure `int`s, I'm not sure about it. I'd probably still accompany it with a comment in my code to point that out because I don't consider it to be expressive enough (as with most implicit things).

Comment: Thanks very much guys, you are so right I am absolutely a beginner and this was the reason I was struggling with this code! Would appreciate if this forum is not for beginners then what should a beginner like me do who is ambitious to learn this language flawlessly and quickly, if  I don't experiment then I won't learn and if I don't ask for pro help then what?