# Why don't max() and min() work efficiently for range objects in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, range, built-in

As [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3) explains, `range` objects in Python 3 are clever enough to be able to test efficiently for membership:

```
In [1]: 1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)
Out[1]: True    # answer returned very quickly
```

However, the same is not true for the evaluation of a `range`'s maximum and minimum values with `max` and `min`, which seems to iterate over the entire sequence to find these values:

```
In [2]: max(range(1000000000000001))   # don't do this
...
```

It would be trivial to implement these functions efficiently for `range` objects, so why hasn't it been done? Is there some implementation detail or edge case I am missing?

Comment: How does `max` know that the sequence is sorted? `max` does not defer to dunder methods, it is a dumb O(n) algorithm that simply iterates over the sequence as given.

Comment: Then that would seem to be the answer: `in` and `len` defer to dunder methods that can be overridden, `max` and `min` do not (and I suppose making them so would be an implementation change too far for this use-case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max` is takes the sequence as given, making no assumptions about the type. The sequence is simply iterated over in O(n) time, regardless of whether it is a `range` object, a list, or a generator.

Some other operators and functions defer to dunder methods which then compute the result. In the case of `range`, `in` calls the `__contains__` dunder method, which then computes whether `low <= item < high`, basically. So it is O(1) in python3.