# Different between in operator and for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

i was wondering if the "in" operator work as a for loop and if the time complexity are equivalent?

```py
for n in range(10):
    if n == 5:
        return True
return False

5 in range(10)
```

Comment: Depends on [the version of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) - see "Changed in version 3.2".

Comment: Internally the `in` operator is doing essentially the same thing as your loop.  However, it should be much faster since it's being run directly by Python.

Comment: Strongly related and worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

They are working differently in these cases.

In the loop, `for variable in iterable` will set `variable` to each element of `iterable`. In your case, `n` will be equal to 0, than 1, than 2... than 9.

In the second case, without the loop, `in` checks if a `variable` in the `iterable`. So in your case it will check if 5 is in the iterator `0-1-2-...-9`.

Let's modify your code with prints:

```
def a():
    for n in range(10):
        print(n)
        if n == 5:
            return True
    return False

a()
print()
print(5 in range(10))
```

It will print:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5

True
```

So in the first case you are set `n` sequentially to 0-9. In the second case you are just checking `5` is in `0-9`.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd approach...

```
5 in range(10)
```

...is much faster. Python’s `range` is lazy iterator. When you check whether a value is in the range of numbers, it can easily be calculated rather than looping over the range. This means there is an `O(1)` time complexity.

The 1st approach however has, at worst, an `O(n)` time complexity as you may have to loop over the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

```
~ $ python -m timeit "def func():
>   for x in range(10):
>     if x == 5:
>       return True
>     return False
> func()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.352 usec per loop

~ $ python -m timeit "5 in range(10)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.263 usec per loop
```

This is easy to test, and i think results aren't big suprise :)