# Why doesn't range return an array but does when I add it to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

Are there any ways `range` print an array without using `list()`?

```py
def every_three_nums(start):
  lst = []
  if start <= 100:
    lst += range(start, 101, 3)
    # this returns an array but if I print(range(start, 101, 3)), it doesn't
    return lst
  else:
    return lst
```

This returns an array but if I `print(range(start, 101, 3))`, it doesn't. Why?
How does this code `lst += range(start, 101, 3)` turn `range` into an array of numbers?

Comment: How do you want to print it?

Comment: An `range` is not a list so printing it doesn't print a list, `range` it is an object the produces values on iteration. You need get those values out with something like `print([x for x in range(start, 101, 3)])`.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081318/) gives you all the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If I `print(range(start, 101, 3))`, it doesn't [return an array]. Why?**

Among the changes that Python 3 made from Python 2 was an emphasis on generators rather than lists or tuples. A list takes up memory for every item in the list, while a generator only creates one item at a time, whenever needed. A generator thus almost always uses less memory, a precious resource in a program. Also, since a generator needs to create only one item (at most) immediately after it is created and the other items may never be needed, it can also save a great deal of time compared to a list which needs to create all its items whether they are needed or not.

Thus many things that made a list in Python 2 were changed to create a generator instead. `range` is one of those items. So range is an object, but the items are created only when asked for in one way or another. So the command `print(range(start, 101, 3))` creates the range object then prints the object. Python prints a note that basically says that the `range` is an object, a special `range` object, and gives a few more details.

As @ShadowRanger points out in a comment (and I meant to include but forgot), `range` is more than a generator. It can work as a sequence (you can pull one item out from the middle, not just the beginning) and has other special characteristics. That is why your command to print a `range` does not just show that it is an object, it shows that it is a `range` object which differs from other objects. I was speaking in general terms when I wrote of "generators"--there are other objects that are similar.

**Are there any ways the `range` function prints an array without using `list()`?**

If you want to print a `range` as a list, ask for the items. There are multiple ways:

```
 print(*range(start, 101, 3))
```

That uses Pythons "splat" operator `*` to get the items of the `range` in a form suitable as parameters to a function--in this case, the `print` function. This method comes the closest to never using a "list" to show the contents of the `range`. The printout is not an "array", just the items separated by spaces.

```
print([*range(start, 101, 3)])
```

This uses splat to create a list, then prints the list.

```
print(list(range(start, 101, 3))
```

That uses apparent type-casting to convert the range to a list immediately so the list can be printed. You said you do not want this method, but I show it for completeness.

```
print(tuple(range(start, 101, 3))
```

This uses a tuple rather than a list.

```
print([v for v in range(start, 101, 3)])
```

That uses a list comprehension to create the list. By adding an `if` clause in the comprehension you could get just some few desired items from the list. You could use a set or other kind of comprehension if you don't want a list.

```
lst = []
lst += range(start, 101, 3)
print(list)
```

For details on this one, see the end of this answer.

```
lst = []
for v in range(start, 101, 3):
    lst.append(v)
print(lst)
```

You could use a loop to get a list to print. There are many variations on this loop that would work.

**How does this code `lst += range(start, 101, 3)` turn `range` into an array of numbers?**

It doesn't. Using the += command on a list uses whatever is on the right side of the operator as an *iterable*, not a list. Your code picks the items one-by-one out of the range and appends them one-by-one to the list. The range is never converted to a list, it is just used to extend a list. You can see that by trying to execute `lst = lst + range(start, 101, 3)`--the range is not converted to a list so an error results.. See [this link](https://lerner.co.il/2019/06/06/why-do-python-lists-let-you-a-tuple-when-you-cant-a-tuple/) for a closely related question, though it talks about tuples rather than ranges.

Comment: Pedantic note: `range` is actually a sequence, not just a generator. It can be iterated multiple times, indexed, sliced, etc. Python 3 made many thing iterator/generator based, but it also used views and other lazy constructs like `range`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You are right, `range` is not just a generator. I meant to include that in my answer but I forgot. Thanks for the reminder--I'll add that now.

Comment: How does this code `lst += range(start, 101, 3)` turn `range` into an array of numbers?

Comment: @SharonNg: `list`'s `+=` operator takes *any* iterable and appends the elements from it to the `list`. It just reads the values from the `range` one at a time and appending them until it's exhausted. It's roughly equivalent to `list.extend`. It doesn't matter what the type of the right hand side is, as long as it's iterable, it will pull elements and append them until they run out.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) return a immutable sequence type, the advantage is that the range object...

> ...will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the
>   size of the range it represents (as it only stores the start, stop and
>   step values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed)

Range used to return a list in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

The key is what:

```
 lst += range(start, 101, 3)
```

does when `lst` is a `list` which is:

```
 lst.extend(range(start, 101, 3))
```

`extend` adds all the items from its argument to the list as if it were:

```
for v in range(start, 101, 3):
    lst.append(v)
```

In both of these it doesn't matter if range returns an iterable or a list as both are iterable and iterate is what `extend` does to get the items from its argument.