# math.pow of a very large integer in Python is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, 64-bit, exponentiation

I am trying to print a very large number by calculating very large powers of an integer. Although my code is correct, i am not observing the desired output.

Generally, python interpreter can print very large integer as much as the system memory supports. With that assumption in mind below is the code i am running.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())

import math
if a in range(1,1001):
    if b in range(1,1001):
        if c in range(1,1001):
            if d in range(1,1001):
                print((math.pow(a,b)+math.pow(c,d)))
```

The output which i am observing is

```
4710194409608608302099333120
```

The output which is expected is

```
4710194409608608369201743232
```

Can you please provide me pointers to how this can be solved?
Input Values are:

```
a = 9
b = 29
c = 7
d = 27
```

Comment: @ggorlen or: `1 <= a <= 1000`

Comment: @ggorlen I don't think that your claim that the range checks are linear is true. See [Why is "1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)" so fast in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/4996248)

Comment: @ggorlen absolutely not true, `range` objects are not iterators, they are sequence-like containers that support constant time membership testing for `int` objects

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new--not sure how I missed that thread. Further reinforcement that I forget the intuitive stuff in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running into the limits of floating point precision. From the documentation:

> Unlike the built-in ** operator, math.pow() converts both its
>   arguments to type float. Use ** or the built-in pow() function for
>   computing exact integer powers.

So just use `**`

```
>> 9**29+7**27
4710194409608608369201743232
```

Comment: BEATEN BY SECONDS!

Comment: I feel your pain. Quite often, in fact.

Answer (score 5):

`math.pow` converts the inputs to `float`

The expected result you are showing is the result you get when you do:

```
x = 9**29
y = 7**27
print(x+y)
```

The result you are seeing comes from this:

```
x = float(9**29)
y = float(7**27)
print(int(x+y))
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
>>> 9 ** 29 + 7 ** 27
4710194409608608369201743232
```