# Math.pow works strangely in Python

Tags: python

Recently,I want to build a program to display an integer digit by digit, but
I met some problems.
 When I tried to print out `math.pow(10,n)`, it worked as expected when `n<23`, but working strangely when`n>23`.

Here are my test codes:

```
for i in range(0,31):
    print('(int) 10 to the',i,'th ==>',int(math.pow(10,i)))
```

The output:

```
*(int) 10 to the 23 th ==> 100000000000000008388608
(int) 10 to the 24 th ==> 999999999999999983222784
(int) 10 to the 25 th ==> 10000000000000000905969664
(int) 10 to the 26 th ==> 100000000000000004764729344
(int) 10 to the 27 th ==> 1000000000000000013287555072
(int) 10 to the 28 th ==> 9999999999999999583119736832
(int) 10 to the 29 th ==> 99999999999999991433150857216
(int) 10 to the 30 th ==> 1000000000000000019884624838656*
```

I also tried not to cast float to int.

```
for i in range(0,31):
print('(float) 10 to the',i,'th ==>',math.pow(10,i))
```

The output:

```
(float) 10 to the 23 th ==> 1.0000000000000001e+23
(float) 10 to the 24 th ==> 1e+24
(float) 10 to the 25 th ==> 1e+25
(float) 10 to the 26 th ==> 1e+26
(float) 10 to the 27 th ==> 1e+27
(float) 10 to the 28 th ==> 1e+28
(float) 10 to the 29 th ==> 1e+29
(float) 10 to the 30 th ==> 1e+30
```

What I expect `math.pow(10,23)` is something like `100...00`.
Are there any ways that could achieve this?

Comment: This feels like an issue due to floating point number precision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) in the math.pow method. Have you considered using the built-in pow method instead?

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow): *"Unlike the built-in \*\* operator, math.pow() converts both its arguments to type float. Use \*\* or the built-in pow() function for computing exact integer powers."*

Comment: @smci No, the results are not correct for integer arithmetic, they are imprecise due to the computation being done with floating-point numbers (regardless of the inputs being of type `int`). See the linked Q&A.

Comment: @kaya3 I got what I want by using the built-in ** operator, many thanks!

Comment: Another duplicate: [math.pow of a very large integer in Python is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814036/printing-a-very-large-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this looks odd .

[Math.pow() returns a float](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_pow.asp).
The floating point number representation has limited precision. This is more apparent when numbers start getting very large or very small.
The loss of precision cannot be fixed  by converting from float to integer.

There's a way to print float numbers without scientific notation.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values).

So you could try and print the numbers like:

```
for i in range(0,31): 
print('(float) 10 to the',i,'th ==>','{:f}'.format(math.pow(10,i)))
```

However since Math.pow is of float type eventually the floating point precision limit will manifest itself.

Instead you can use the python **exponentiation operator**.

```
 for i in range(0,31): 
 print('(float) 10 to the',i,'th ==>',10 ** i)
```

The python exponentiation operator will always return an integer when the two arguments are integers.
The operator is `**` and assuming `X ** Y` it raises the number `X` to the power `Y`