# Unexpected result when returning a boolean from a function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, boolean

I'm trying to write a Pyhon function that checks whether a list contains a given index number.

```
def ncheck(n, list):
    for x in range(len(list)):
        if n == x:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I tested the code with the following arguments:

```
print(ncheck(6, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
print(ncheck(2, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

I expected the first run to return `False` since it's looking for index 6 on a list with 4 elements and the second run to return `True` because it's looking for index 2. What actually happens is both runs return `False`. I thought that maybe having `return` inside the if block caused the problem, so I tried assigning another variable "answer" inside the if block and returning this variable as the closing statement for the function but got the same result:

```
def ncheck(n, list):
    for x in range(len(list)):
        if n == x:
            answer = True
        else:
            answer = False
    return answer

print(ncheck(6, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
print(ncheck(2, [0, 1, 2, 3]))

False
False
```

I'm at a loss. More than an alternate way to solve this issue, I want to understand why this method specifically isn't working.

Comment: ```list``` in python is a built in function so now you shadow it inside your function so use a different name.

Comment: But why not just `return n < len(list)`? (putting aside `list` being a bad variable name as mentioned by @Khaled) or even better, just catching an `IndexError` wherever you intend to call this function?

Comment: You should have used a debugger before asking the question here. Learn about pdb and debugging in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently just checks the **first** number, your `else` is intended to run if *all* numbers don't match:

```
def ncheck(n, list):
    for x in range(len(list)):
        if n == x:
            return True
    return False # after exiting the for loop

print(ncheck(6, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
print(ncheck(2, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Returns

```
False
True
```

Additionally, note that `range` is actually capable of doing this as an O(1)  operation, so the preferred way of doing this (independent of the length of `list`) is:

```
def ncheck(n, list):
    return n in range(len(list))
```

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933679/11659881) for more details.

Comment: or just `return n < len(list)`

Comment: using last method will just work if array is actually just increments of  1 and will fail if arrays is not this number sequence.

Comment: @DeepSpace The example in the question checks the range, which means that in this case, negative values of `n` are not desired.

Comment: @Khaled I interpret the question as "how can I check if `n` is a valid, non-negative index into my list". You can see from OP's example that they use `range` as well because they are not trying to compare to the elements in the list, so the elements in the list should be irrelevant.

Comment: @Kraigolas OP is merely trying to compare `n` to the **length** of the list, which, by definition, can not be negative, so I'm not sure what negative numbers have to do with this. If you really want to guard against getting `True` for negative *inputs*, just have `return 0 <= n < len(list)`. There is really no need for a confusing loop here