# Generate random non repeating pairs of numbers within 2 ranges

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I want to create random pairs of numbers within 2 ranges.

So for example if I want 3 random pairs of numbers where 10 < n1 < 20 and 30 < n2 < 50 then an acceptable output would be this: `[[11,35],[15,30],[15,42]]` but not `[[11,35],[11,35],[12,39]]`

I would like an efficient (both computationally and memory wise) algorithm to do this. The language doesn't really matter because I can adapt it later (although Python would be preferred).

So far the best idea I have had is to create a dictionary with all the possible numbers in n1 and as values a list of the numbers which have been used in n2. Then I can just pick a random n1 and find a number which hasn't been used in n1[n2] set.

This isn't very efficient space wise though and I'm hoping for something better. It also seems to be computationally inefficient to find a number not in n1[n2] many times.

I could also do the opposite and have the dictionary populated with all the numbers not used and just pop a random number off the list. But this would use much more space.

Is there any efficient way to do this? Is this a common problem?

Edit: It would be good if this could easily be expanded to more dimensions (so sets of N numbers). But this isn't really needed yet.

Comment: Do the generated pairs conform to a uniform distribution?

Comment: "Should they" or "Do they" in the one I already created? Well they should but I haven't really checked that in the one I created yet since it's not working very well due to the complexity issues mentioned

Comment: Yeah, I mean the "Should they", i.e. the expected results.

Comment: The infamous question of the non-repeating random numbers. I always wonder if there is a real reason for not wanting repetition or if it is just the false belief that repeating outcomes is not random.

Comment: In this case I'm starting to think its okay-ish to have repeating values. The idea was that I want to train a neural network and I was generating some input data for it. I didn't want repetition so that when I run the validation data it wouldn't be fed values its already seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer pair `(x, y)` in `[min_x, min_x + s) X [min_y, min_y + t)` can be mapped to an integer `m` within the 1D space `[min_x * t, (min_x + s) * t)` by calculating `m = x * t + y - min_y`. The inverse mapping from `m` to `(x, y)` can be achieved by `(m // t, min_y + m % t)` in Python.

Therefore the problem is transformed to choosing multiple values from `[min_x * t, (min_x + s) * t)` without replacement (i.e. no duplicates in the returned sequence). This can be done by simply calling the [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function in Python. According to the doc, the underlying implementation is space efficient for sequence inputs. So the entire problem can be done in Python as shown in the following:

```
from random import sample

# max_x and max_y are exclusive while min_x and min_y are inclusive
t = max_y - min_y
sampled_pairs = [(m//t, min_y + m%t) for m in sample(range(min_x * t, max_x * t), k=3)]
```

Comment: I was thinking of this (it builds on my solution which I deleted). But I was worried that `range(min_x * t, max_x *t)` will use a lot of space. I guess I was wrong. I'll read that function at some point and see if I can figure out how it works.

Comment: Just to point out though: After reading the source code for `sample` it seems that if the sample size is large enough it will create a list of the input range. In that scenario it would be just as efficient as the methods I've proposed. In the event that the sample size I want is low then it will be more efficient though

Comment: @KNejad In Python 3 `range(...)` returns range objects which are basically a special class of objects that have `start`, `stop`, and `step` fields so it is efficient (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3)). As for the `sample` function, the implementation creates a list of the input when the size of the set needed for holding the samples is larger than that.