# Does list instantiates at every iteration of python 'for' loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I want to know if the **list** created (instantiated) and used in **for** loop will reduce efficiency of my program.

**For example:**

```
for i in range(1, 10000):
     print("This i = ", i)
```

Please tell me if the list **[1,2,3,...,10000]** (which is **range(1,10000)**) will be generated (or instantiated) at every iteration or not. Because if Yes, then this is a huge overhead and inefficient program.

**Actually I want to use it like this:**

```
with open("bbc.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as bbcFile:
    for headline in BS(REQ.get("https://www.bbc.com").text, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'media__content'}):
        bbcFile.write(" ".join(headline.text.split()) + "\n\n")
```

Comment: A `range` relies on a generator, so no, no list will be generated 10000 times

Comment: In Python 3... `range(...)` doesn't produce a list at all...

Comment: There is no `range()` in your "actual" example. BeautifulSoup _will_ construct in-memory lists at some point, though.

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci Not exactly a generator. It's a custom object, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3

Comment: Actually it's an iterable - but a lazy one indeed.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers well... can also act as a sequence in terms of indexing due to some maths...

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the update, I missed that point obviously.

Comment: Not that one wants to do something like: `range(12345, 1000000000, 74)[-7]` or some other convoluted example often :)

Comment: @AKX I actually though that range(a, b) is a collection and the BeatifulSoup resultSet having all headlines tags is a collection as well.

Comment: @AliSajjad it *is* a collection, it is not a generator at all, it isn't even an iterator. It does **not** produce a `list` object though, but a `range` object, which is a specialized sequence-like object that does not store all the items it "contains" in memory at once, rather, arithmetic sequences can be represented efficiently with simply a `start`, `stop`, `step`

Answer (score 2):

In a Python for-statement, [as defined by the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

According to the aforementioned docs,

> The **expression list is evaluated once**; it should yield an iterable
>   object. An iterator is created for the result of the `expression_list`.
>   The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the
>   iterator, in the order returned by the iterator. Each item in turn is
>   assigned to the `target list` using the standard rules for assignments
>   (see Assignment statements), and then the `suite` is executed.

So no, whatever expression you are using in to produce an iterable is only evaluated once. You could test this out yourself:

```
>>> class MyIterable:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print("Initialized")
...     def __iter__(self):
...         yield from (1,2,3)
...
>>> for x in MyIterable():
...     print(x)
...
Initialized
1
2
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3, no. `range(1, 10000)` creates a range object that produces items when necessary:

```
>>> range(1, 10000)
range(1, 10000)
>>> type(range(1, 10000))
<class 'range'>
```

So there is never a list `[1, ..., 10000]` stored in memory.

A great SO question to check out is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3), which explains the `range` object.

Comment: i think the issue is whether the expression for the iterable in the for-statment is re-evaluated on each iteration, so take for example `for x in list(range(10000)): ...`