# Trying to calculate even odd without math operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
w= int(input('enter a num:'))
even= []
for x in range (0, 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 2):
    even.append(x)
    if w in even:
        print ('the num is even')
        break
else:
    print ('the num is odd')
```

Comment: That loop will take a very long time to execute and produce a list very big. You'd be better off just writing `even = range(0, 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 2)` which will work instantly and you can immediately check if `w in even`

Comment: Note: you can test if a number is odd with out math operators by testing if the least significant bit is 1 (integers only).

Comment: I appreciate setting a challenge for yourself. For this, what exactly do you consider to be "Math Operators"? I imagine `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `**` are off the table. It looks like you're trying not to use `==`. What about bitwise operators? Any others?

Comment: Even without bitwise operators, it would be simpler to convert the number to a string and test if the last char is in "13579".

Answer (score 1):

Though the idea works, that loop would take a very long time to execute and produce a list very big. You'd be better off just using the `range` object directly.

```
w= int(input('enter a num:'))
even = range(0, 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 2)
if w in even:
    print("the number is even")
else:
    print("the number is odd")
```

which will work instantly (though only for numbers between zero and that big top number). The `range` object can figure out whether it contains any given number by its own internal arithmetic without having to do any iteration.

(Python 3 only)

Comment: For someone less familiar with Python's inner workings, how could this possible work instantly? I can see maybe how Python doesn't actually create a list of every even number, but wouldn't Python have to iterate in order to determine if the number was actually in the range? Maybe inputting `2` is fast, but wouldn't `999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998` take a longer time?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn It figures out whether the range contains any particular number intelligently, using arithmetic based on the endpoints and the step. Checking `999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998` is just as fast as any other number.

Comment: I noticed. I thought about it using endpoints but tests with numbers like `500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (dead center in the middle of the range) still execute seemingly instantly. I might ask my own SO question about this. I'm intrigued.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Don't bother: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3

Comment: "only for numbers between zero and that big top number" - Not true, it also works for infinitely many numbers outside that range :-)

Comment: @superbrain Yes, I suppose. "Works" in the way a stopped clock works.

Comment: @khelwood can you validate what i asked. I found your answer better but i want to know how to validate my vode. 
Pls help

Comment: @GauravChanda I don't understand what else you're asking for.