# python - different behavior of print(*generator, <element>)

Tags: python, generator

## Question

Please help understand why the two cases act differently although both use a generator `(i for i in range(5))`.

```
>>> print(i for i in range(5))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc409c02900>
>>> print(*(i for i in range(5)))
0 1 2 3 4
>>> print(*(i for i in range(5)), 5)
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

```
>>> _r = (i for i in range(5))
>>> print(_r)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc409c029e0>
>>> print(*_r)
0 1 2 3 4
>>> print(*_r, 5)
5
>>> print(*(_r), 5)
5
```

Comment: The first `*_r` consumes the generator, thus the second `*_r` is empty, and you just print `5` after that

Comment: You can't reuse a generator instance, you'd have to create a new generator instance first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `*` operator on a generator expression (or any iterator for that matter), it consumes it:

```py
my_iterator = (i for i in range(3))

second_iterator = iter(list(range(3)))

# splat operator consumes the generator expression
print(*my_iterator)
0 1 2
print(*my_iterator, "Empty!")
Empty!

# splat operator also consumes the iterator
print(*second_iterator)
0 1 2
print(*second_iterator, "Also empty!")
Also empty!
```

You'd need to recreate it to re-use it, which is what you're doing in your first example:

```py
s = (i for i in range(3))
print(*s)
0 1 2

# You create a new generator expression/iterator
s = (i for i in range(3))
print(*s)
0 1 2

# And so it isn't empty
# same with the shorthand
print(*(i for i in range(3))
0 1 2
```

### Note on `range`

Since I've used `range` for this example, it's important to note that `range` doesn't share this behavior, but an *iterator* over `range` does:

```py
x = range(3)

print(*x)
0 1 2

print(*x)
0 1 2
# the range object isn't consumed and can be re-used

a = iter(x)

print(*a)
0 1 2

print(*a)

# prints nothing because `a` has been exhausted
```

More detail can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081894/7867968)