# How to replace items in a list?

Tags: python

Please help me.
I am a noob and the code does not run. The input should be a number which indicates the index where  the 0 turns to an 1.

```
board2 =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
inp = input('Input Number 0-8:')
if inp == int():
    a = inp
    for i in board2:
        board2.replace(i[a],1)
        return board2
```

Comment: how can you iterate through `int()`

Comment: You say "the code does not run."  Please add the error message you get.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with this code, well *before* hitting the point where ``'list' object has no attribute 'replace'``. Did you go through [the python.org tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) already?

Comment: `boad2[3] = 10` will replace the fourth element of `board2` with `10`. Not sure that is enough to fix the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value input is both an int and if it is in range that you described.

Then you can use the index to replace the value in board2 to 1.

Also, the `input()` function defaults to string.

```
board2 =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
inp = input('Input Number 0-8:')
if 0 <= int(inp) < len(board2):
    board2[int(inp)] = 1
print(board2)
```

Comment: Don't use `range` for a bound check, thats very inefficient. Do `if 0 <= int(inp) < len(board2):`

Comment: @flakes Using `range` for checking bounds is perfectly fine, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3).

Comment: @Asocia true its not as bad as it could be, but it's still about 4x slower than the `if` variant. There's a lot of extra objects allocated for that expense: https://gist.github.com/cal-pratt/1e8c752751e50fa63ca7610547ee9793

Comment: @flakes Yes, you are right. Actually most of the time is spent with the function call. If you define the range above the function like `my_range = range(250, 750)` and then use it inside the `range_check` its performance is not that bad. I wouldn't mind using it if it's a few nanoseconds slower than the `if` check. Thanks for clarifying it though.

Comment: @Asocia Yeah, at that point you're doing more work to use range and are losing the initially intended readability advantage (although IMHO the double bounded `if` is generally a more readable/ Pythonic way to write this in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! you don't really need to use "replace" here; you can just modify the element which resides at the index provided directly. The only criteria you would need to consider is that the number is greater than zero AND within the range of the "board2" list provided.

```
board2 =[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
inp = input('Input Number 0-8:')
if (0 < int(inp) < len(board2)):
    board2[int(inp)] = 1
    print(*board2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should solve your question:

```
board2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

index = int(input('Input Number 0-8:'))

if index in range(len(board2)):
    board2[index] = 1

print(board2)
```