# How could I make my code work parallelize with dask?

Tags: python, numpy, dask-delayed

First import some packages:

```
import numpy as np
from dask import delayed
```

Suppose I have two NumPy arrays:

```
a1 = np.ones(5000000)
a2 = np.ones(8000000)
```

I would like to show **the sum and length of the two arrays**, and the functions are shown as:

```
def sum(x):
  result = 0
  for data in x:
      result = result + data
  return result, len(x)

def get_result(x, y):
  return x, y
```

I have two examples in colab, the **sequential** example is like this:

```
%%time
result1 = sum(a1)
result2 = sum(a2)
result = get_result(result1, result2)
print(result)
```

And the output is:

```
((5000000.0, 5000000), (8000000.0, 8000000))
CPU times: user 1.41 s, sys: 3.7 ms, total: 1.42 s
Wall time: 1.42 s
```

However, I would like to compute these values **parallelly**.

```
result1 = delayed(sum)(a1)
result2 = delayed(sum)(a2)
result = delayed(get_result)(result1, result2)
result = result.compute()
print(result)
```

And the output is:

```
Delayed('get_result-ffbb6330-1014-42c5-b625-06e3e66a56ed')
CPU times: user 1.42 s, sys: 7.97 ms, total: 1.42 s
Wall time: 1.43 s
```

Why **the second program didn't work parallelly**? Because **the wall time two examples are almost the same**.

Comment: The `sum` function you wrote is very inefficient. Please don't do that. Use `np.sum` instead. Trying to run in parallel very inefficient code just use more computing resources for no reason. For more information about why this is so inefficient, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584027 .

Comment: I know the program works worse than NumPy functions. it's just a demo. The code in Dask tutorial is similar to that in my question. The point is that programs cannot be executed in parallel.