# Transform each row of a numpy array into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, nested, transformation, numpy-ndarray

I have the following `ndarray`:

```
array([[0.00000, 0.00000,  50.00000],
       [0.00000, 10.02227, 50.00000],
       [0.00000, 20.04454, 50.00000],
       [0.00000, 30.06682, 50.00000],
       [0.00000, 40.08909, 50.00000]])
```

and I would like to transform each row into a separate `ndarray` in order to have a nested `ndarray` structure:

```
array([[array([0.00000, 0.00000,  50.00000])],
       [array([0.00000, 10.02227, 50.00000])],
       [array([0.00000, 20.04454, 50.00000])],
       [array([0.00000, 30.06682, 50.00000])],
       [array([0.00000, 40.08909, 50.00000])]])
```

I've tried with:

```
new_array = numpy.apply_along_axis(np.array, 1, old_array)
```

but did not succeed because `new_array` is equal to `old_array`.

How can I transform my array? I guess there should be a solution using a `for` cycle, but is there a more pythonic alternative?

Comment: Note that working with arrays of array object is generally far less inefficient.

Comment: Did you mean far less efficient?

Comment: It should be significantly slower (and also take more memory space regarding the actual shape).

Comment: What is a more efficient alternative? A list of arrays? And in case I want to have a 2D array of array objects, should I prefer a list of list of array objects?

Comment: ND arrays are generally fast as long as you work on *native types*. If you work on object, then all alternatives are slow (because of the CPython interpreter) but I think lists should be faster in that case (list of lists). Numpy array can be used for convenience but not speed in such a case. Related post: [Why is `np.sum(range(N))` very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584027).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to achieve this, as a list of `np.array` makes more sense, but you could do this:

```
new_array = np.zeros((old_array.shape[0], 1), dtype = 'O')
new_array[:] = [[x] for x in old_array]
new_array
```

output:

```
array([[array([ 0.,  0., 50.])],
       [array([ 0.     , 10.02227, 50.     ])],
       [array([ 0.     , 20.04454, 50.     ])],
       [array([ 0.     , 30.06682, 50.     ])],
       [array([ 0.     , 40.08909, 50.     ])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to have a 2D `np.array` where each element is a 1x3 `np.array`, representing xyz coordinates. Does this make sense in your opinion or a list of list of `np.array` would be better?

Comment: @fma: why not simply use a 3D array of shape (m, n, 3)?

Comment: That's definitely an option, thanks