# python range() does not check numbers within?

Tags: python

quick question. Why in the below code for 'word search' leetcode, does the code

```py
if ( row not in range(rows) or  
col not in range(columns) or
```

not work, while replacing it with

```py
if ( row < 0 or row >= rows or 
col < 0 or col >= columns or
```

work? The purpose is to see if the row and col is out of bounds of the matrix.
Below is my full code.

```py
class Solution:
    def exist(self, board: List[List[str]], word: str) -> bool:
        # Backtracking dfs
        rows = len(board)
        columns = len(board[0])
        if 2 in range(2):
            print('ye')
        # Make sure not to visit same cell
        path = set()
        
        def dfs(row, col, ind):
            if ind == len(word):
                return True
            # Check if out of bounds,
            # or if we already visited this cell,
            # or not right letter
            if ( row not in range(rows) or  ## DOESN'T WORK ##################
            col not in range(columns) or    ### STUCK IN INFINITE ##########
            (row, col) in path or
            board[row][col] != word[ind] ):
                return False
            
            # Otherwise, mark self as visited path, and
            # call for all other directions
            else:
                path.add((row, col))
                bottom = dfs(row + 1, col, ind + 1)
                top = dfs(row - 1, col, ind + 1)
                right = dfs(row, col + 1, ind + 1)
                left = dfs(row, col - 1, ind + 1)
                # Done with this layer, remove from visited
                path.remove((row, col))
                # Return True if any paths returned True
                return bottom or top or right or left
            
        
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(columns):
                # Start word with each letter to check
                if dfs(row, col, 0): return True
                
        return False
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I used the following code for 'number of islands' leetcode,
you can see below that range() is used successfully. so i don't know why it doesn't work in the above code.

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        if not grid:
            return 0
        
        visited = set()   
        rows, columns = len(grid), len(grid[0])            
        islands = 0
        
        def bfs(row, column):
            # Store top, bottom, left, right directions
            directions = [ [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1] ]
            
            # Already added to visited earlier
            queue = [ (row, column) ]  
            while queue:
                popped = queue.pop(0)
                for [vertical, horizontal] in directions:
                    new_row = popped[0] + vertical
                    new_column = popped[1] + horizontal
                    new_point = (new_row, new_column)
                    
                    # Before adding new point, check if 
                    # point is within the grid's bounds,
                    # is equal to '1', 
                    # and is not visited yet
                    #
                    # Cannot have new_row < rows and new_column < columns,
                    # then negative index would pass...
                    if (new_row in range(rows) and 
                    new_column in range(columns) and 
                    grid[new_row][new_column] == '1' and 
                    new_point not in visited):
                            visited.add( (new_point) )
                            queue.append( new_point )
```

Comment: @S3DEV true, thanks. But I am not sure why range() is not working here.. I even tested printed out the for loop to make sure I wasn't crazy.. i used range() to check within-bounds numbers for 'number of islands' so idk why it does not work here

Comment: @S3DEV range is not a function, it's an object, and it does `in` check in O(1). Also, OP checks `not in`, so it's not `0<row<=rows`, it *could* be `not 0<=row<rows` (see where the equals are), "not (p and q)" instead of "not p or not q" has to be properly negated

Comment: @S3DEV See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3 for details. Using `range` is fine.

Comment: @S3DEV when using an "in" check with ranges it does NOT iterate all the numbers. It is done mathematically. - its O(1).

Comment: just to clarify, if only the range() parts are replaced as I stated above, then it works. Its strange

Comment: @h4z3 - Yep, that important detail slipped my mind.  Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @9769953 if the function were to be only executed in that double for loop, then yes. But it's not, it's recursive, as DFS usually is.

Comment: @h4z3 Ah yes, I overlooked the recursion steps.

Comment: @RachelKim Could you give an input example where this fails for you? I just copied your code and used a few example, and all completed promptly, with the correct answer.

Comment: @9769953 yea, I used the code for 'word search' leetcode. when I execute the code on that leetcode problem, it fails