# How to print the numbers that do not belong to the interval

Tags: c#

I have to  generate random `100`  integers  from an array belonging to the interval `[0 .. 132]`  and i have to output those which do not belong to the interval `(26 .. 100]`

I don't know how to output those which do not belong to the interval. I hope someone can give me some guidance. I'm struggling to find information on internet

My first part of the code is:

```
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i=1; i <=100; i++)
            {
                int x = rand.Next(0, 132);
            }
```

Comment: `if(x < 26 || x > 100) // do something`?

Comment: `if (x <= 26 || x > 100) Console.WriteLine(x);` be careful with `<=` and `>`, we accept `26` and reject `100` since `(26..100]` interval is semiopen. Same is for - `rand.Next(0, 132 + 1)`: we accept `132`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating random numbers which you don't use, generate the ones you need directly:

```cs
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i=1; i <=100; i++)
{
    int x = rand.Next(0, 26-0 + 132-101);
    if (x>26) x+=101-26;
}
```

If the ranges get more complicated, you could use LINQ to construct a concatentation of ranges and take a random from there:

```cs
Random rand = new Random(); 
var nums = Enumerable.Range(0,27).Concat(Enumerable.Range(101,32));
for (int i=1; i <=100; i++)     
{
    int x = nums.Skip(rand.Next(0,nums.Count())).First();
}
```

Don't do that for large ranges. According to [@Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) it can become very slow.

You can also use an `if` statement as suggested in many comments. But then you need to count the valid numbers and use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop:

```cs
Random rand = new Random();
var count = 0;
while (count < 100)
{
    int x = rand.Next(0, 132);
    if (x <= 26 || x > 100)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1. Using `if` selection statement

Just check that `x` value is more than 100 *OR* value is less than 27:

```cs
if (x < 27 || x > 100)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

### Method 2. Using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) LINQ method

Generate range and check that `x` value does *NOT* include in specified range:

```cs
if (!Enumerable.Range(27, 100).Contains(x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

WARNING: Using this method with large range can have a significant impact on increasing the execution time.

Comment: `!Enumerable.Range(27, 100).Contains(x)` is *dangerous*: when argument(s) is huge, e.g. `!Enumerable.Range(27, 1_000_000_000).Contains(x)` it can be *very slow*. Please, don't recommend such things (or at least add a *warning*, *disclaimer*)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: really? Since [in Python that's incredibly fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3). I don't see why it can't have a similar implementation in C#.

Comment: @Thomas Weller: in c# `Enumerable.Range(start, length).Contains(x)` will enumerate `start`, `start + 1`, `start + 2`, ..., `start + length - 1` items until either `x` is found or all items are enumerated. If `length` is large (and `x` is not found early), the code is slow.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: that's bad. Someone should change the implementation.

Comment: @Thomas Weller: please, fiddle yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/msR7Ft it required for me ~ **6 seconds** to find out that `1_234_567_890` is out of `[26..1_000_000_26)` range

Comment: You are, probably, looking for `Range` type (left and right borders), not for *enumeration* `Enumerable.Range(...)` which enumerates items within given interval