# Why does the range element in my code have problems when is uses the last number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, range

I am using the following code, which just selects a random number from a range and uses it as chance for other elements to be selected, and it works fine with no errors, but occasionally the number that it selects from the range(usually the last number like 16 or 20) does not work, and I don't know why.

Code:

```
import random

# List used for Age Classifications
ageClass = ["Newborn", "Young", "Aged", "Old", "Ancient", "Timeless"]
randAgeClass = ""
randAge = 0

# Probability of age classes
# Newer classes are much more likely to be selected than the older classes
chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
# Chance Debug
print(chance)

if chance in range(1, 5):
    randAgeClass = "Newborn"
elif chance in range(6, 10):
    randAgeClass = "Young"
elif chance in range(11, 13):
    randAgeClass = "Aged"
elif chance in range(14, 16):
    randAgeClass = "Old"
elif chance in range(17, 18):
    randAgeClass = "Ancient"
elif chance in range(19, 20):
    randAgeClass = "Timeless"
else:
    print("error")

# If statements for age classes
if randAgeClass == "Newborn":
    randAge = random.randrange(1, 20)
elif randAgeClass == "Young":
    randAge = random.randrange(21, 80)
elif randAgeClass == "Aged":
    randAge = random.randrange(81, 250)
elif randAgeClass == "Old":
    randAge = random.randrange(251, 500)
elif randAgeClass == "Ancient":
    randAge = random.randrange(501, 1000)
elif randAgeClass == "Timeless":
    randAge = random.randrange(1001, 6000)
else:
    print("error")

print("Vampire Name: Steve")
print("Age Classification:", randAgeClass)
print("Age:", randAge)
```

Here is how a successful output looks like:
[image]

And here is how an unsuccessful output looks like:
[image]

This only seems to be happening if the random number in the range that is chosen is the last number in the range like 5, 10, 16... Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

I tried using a list and that didn't work, so I would rather just use a range for this.

Comment: Python's [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is end-exclusive. Use `range(1, 5)` for 1 through 4 and `range(5, 10)` for 5 through 9, etc.

Comment: So `range(1, 5)` ends at 4 and `range(6, 10)` starts at 6. No 5 in this!

Comment: Note also that a much better way to do this would be to use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with weights.

Comment: `random.randrange()` includes the last number in its range, but `range()` does not.

Comment: You could rewrite those if statements as `if 1 <= chance <= 5:`

Comment: Have you thought about how you could use a dictionary to control this and thus avoid repeating the literal strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your ranges:

```
if chance in range(1, 6):
    randAgeClass = "Newborn"
elif chance in range(6, 11):
    randAgeClass = "Young"
elif chance in range(11, 14):
    randAgeClass = "Aged"
elif chance in range(14, 17):
    randAgeClass = "Old"
elif chance in range(17, 19):
    randAgeClass = "Ancient"
elif chance in range(19, 21):
    randAgeClass = "Timeless"
else:
    print("error")
```

It is **end exclusive**.

[range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalker you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

`range` excludes the upper boundary.

That said, and even if [`x in range(y, z)` is fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/16343464), this is not a very pythonic way to write your conditions.

Rather take advantage of the `elif` and only check the upper bound after the first `if`:

```
if 1 <= chance <= 5:
    randAgeClass = "Newborn"
elif chance <= 10:
    randAgeClass = "Young"
elif chance <= 13:
    randAgeClass = "Aged"
elif chance <= 16:
    randAgeClass = "Old"
elif chance <= 18:
    randAgeClass = "Ancient"
elif chance <= 20:
    randAgeClass = "Timeless"
else:
    print("error")
```

You could also avoid the many conditions using [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to perform a binary search:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

lst    = [      0,         5,      10,     13,    16,        18,         20, float('inf')]
labels = ['error', 'Newborn', 'Young', 'Aged', 'Old', 'Ancient', 'Timeless',      'error']
randAgeClass = labels[bisect_left(lst, chance)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where providing you take care in building the CONTROL structure you have far less runtime code.

Don't forget that the second argument passed to *randrange()* is not included (unlike *randint()*)

As written, 'Error' will never be printed. If you change values either in the control structure or when calculating the *chance* value, then it could happen

```
from random import randrange

CONTROL = {
    "Newborn": ((1, 5), (1, 20)),
    "Young": ((5, 10), (20, 80)),
    "Aged": ((10, 13), (80, 250)),
    "Old": ((13, 16), (250, 500)),
    "Ancient": ((16, 18), (500, 1000)),
    "Timeless": ((18, 20), (1000, 6000))
}

print(chance := randrange(1, 20))

for k, (v1, v2) in CONTROL.items():
    if chance in range(*v1):
        print("Age classification:", k)
        print("Age:", randrange(*v2))
        break
else:
    print('Error')
```

**Sample output:**

```
9
Age classification: Young
Age: 58
```