# How do I define __contains__ for a Python Generator() returned by a function?

Tags: python

The following example:

```py
def myGenerator():
    i = -1
    while i < 1000000:
        print(f"iterating {i}")
        i+=1
        yield i

print(9999 in myGenerator())
```

Prints in the console

```
...
iterating 9994
iterating 9995
iterating 9996
iterating 9997
iterating 9998
True
```

The generator iterates over all items until it finds '9999' *(which in the end of the day then makes it rather pointless to use a generator to begin with as opposed to having my function return a tuple or a list)*.

Would it be possible to define `__contains__` on the `Generator()` object returned by my `myGenerator` function to avoid iterating over all items ? If so, how?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why is "1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)" so fast in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a class implementing `__iter__`, `__next__` & `__contains__` as such:

```py
class myGenerator():
    i=-1
    def __iter__(self):
        self.i=-1
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.__contains__(self.i):
            self.i+=1
            print(f"iterating {self.i}")
            return self.i
        raise StopIteration()
    def __contains__(self, __value):
        return __value < 1000000
i2 = -1
for i in myGenerator():
    i2+=1
    if i2>3:
        break
    
print(9999 in myGenerator())
```

Which would print

```
iterating 0
iterating 1
iterating 2
iterating 3
iterating 4
True
```

Supporting iteration, just like a generator, whilst allowing a custom `__contains__`. The **downside of this approach** however is that creating a class in this fashion requires a lot **more boilerplate** than the generator yield syntax.

Comment: `__next__` should *raise* `StopIteration`, not return an instance of it.

Comment: I would also like to ask, what do I actually call a class like this? Can I still refer to it as a generator? "Iterator"?

Comment: To start, a generator function is a function defined by `def` when it uses a `yield` statement. When you call a generator function, you get back an object of type `generator`. `generator` is just one type that implements the iterator protocol;  it defines both `__iter__` (making it an iterable) and `__next__` (make it an iterator). Most people, when they say "generator", really mean an iterator. I try to use the work "generator" only to refer to the specific iterable type returned by a generator function.

Comment: (Not all iterable types are also iterators. Take `list` for example: it is not an iterator, because `list.__next__` is not defined. It is iterable, because `list.__iter__` returns a value of type `list_iterator`, which *is*--as its name suggests--an iterator, with `list_iterator.__next__` producing a value from the underlying list.)

Comment: So `myGenerator` is both an iterator and an iterable; it is, loosely speaking, a generator, but it is not a `generator`.

Comment: By the way, `range` is similar to the kind of type you are thinking of. A `range` value is iterable (though not an iterator; `range.__iter__` returns a value of type `range_iterator`), and also supports `__contains__` without having to use an iterator. `v in range(x, y)` is basically implemented as `x <= v <= y`.

Comment: This is broken in several ways. (1) `__iter__` shouldn't reset `i`. (2) `__contains__` shouldn't ignore it (i.e., if you've already iterated past `3`, then `3 in myiterator` should return `False`). (3) Your test makes no sense, advancing one iterator and then creating a new one in `9999 in myGenerator()`.

Comment: One more: (4) When I create a generator iterator yielding the numbers from 0 to 100000 and I ask `9999 in myiterator`, then the next value I expect it to yield is 10000. That's how the original generator in your question behaves. This thing in your answer doesn't, as its `__contains__` doesn't affect `i`. I actually started writing a solution myself, but now I'm not confident enough that what I'd be doing is what you want or that you even know what you want...

Comment: @KellyBundy: *"`__contains__` shouldn't ignore [`i`] (i.e., if you've already iterated past 3, then `3 in myiterator` should return `False`"* — are you sure?  I mean, it's not explicitly listed as a requirement.  Sure, generator object behaves the way you described, but it might be the unwanted behaviour.  For example, `range.__contains__()` doesn't advance iterator.

Comment: @NikolajŠ. A `range` **isn't** even an iterator. So that doesn't really have to do with this question. And sure, you could make it behave in highly unconventional highly unexpected ways, but that's breaking expectations and conventions, and hence I consider it broken. Also, I really just pointed those issues out, since they're problematic and I suspect the OP might not have realized them. It **is** their question, so they have the final say in what they're asking for, so I didn't downvote this (which I would've if this had been posted by anyone else).

Comment: @KellyBundy Good spotting :) I was not particularly precise when writing this class. It was mostly to demonstrate the syntax of the magic methods and how to use them - as opposed to solving a real world problem (feel free to make any changes to my answer).